# Find an exact commit timestamp for a database at which no open transactions exist

Tags: oracle

I have a question to a problem that we are trying to solve in Oracle.

Previously in DB2, the company created a copy of their production system daily. They call it the shadow system. When the shadow system is created the team or whatever/whoever is provided with a timestamp which fulfills the requirement that it is the last committed transaction and no other transaction was open at that commit timestamp. They used that timestamp as a *cutting moment* (I know it may sound weird, the point is that we see it as a cut throug the system; it is consistent before and after that cut). Up until that timestamp the data is consistent, which is important us.

The next day, after the shadow system is created anew again, they use that *cutting moment*/timestamp to fetch all the new data that was created after that *cutting moment*.

Now we are using an Oracle database and we are expected to implement the replication ourselves (as a temporary solution).

My question is: Can I extract from the Oracle DBMS such a commit timestampt that is like that *cutting moment* ?

Comment: What method of database duplication are you using? What is the purpose of the "shadow" database? Typically you specify that "moment" when you duplicate or export, and Oracle produces a logically consistent dataset for that point in time, assuming it isn't too far in the past such that UNDO info is no longer available. You wouldn't have to determine on your own when the "optimal" point in time is. Most duplication and export methods don't lend themselves to tracking incremental changes, though.

Comment: Also note that Oracle tracks transactions against the entire instance collectively, not individual schemas, so there's pretty much *never* a time when there are *no* pending transactions. It uses the UNDO records to generate a transactionally consistent picture of the data at a time *you* select (within the scope of the UNDO guaranteed retention period).

Answer (score 2):

Given the way that oracle "does" Transactions (everything runs until one find that it can't anymore and fails), I'd be *very surprised* if you could find such thing.

That said, I'm not sure you *need* to.

The Oracle equivalent you're looking for is a "**Snapshot Standby**" Database and is supported by **Data Guard** (the *free* one, *not* "Active" Data Guard that you have to pay for).

- First, you establish a **Physical Standby** database, which gets replicated in [near] real-time from your Primary Database.  Being a Physical Standby, it is permanently in "recovery" mode and cannot be accessed.
- Then, when you want to start using your Snapshot, you use the DataGuard Broker to "unplug" it from your Primary Database and open it as a "regular" database (a single command).  The data in this database will be *as of* the point of "unplugging" - no uncommitted changes.
- You use this database through the day, just as you would normally.
- Overnight, you "plug" it back in to DataGuard, which uses **Flashback Database** to rewind anything that's happened in it back to the point of "unplugging" and then *rolls forward* all the Redo that's been generated in the *Primary* Database during the day.

Now, obviously, this all needs *a lot* of disk space, to hold the Flashback Database Logs *and* a day's worth of Production Redo, but it should suit your needs.